# on click event on .swf

Tags: flash

I am developing a project in which I need to open popup on clicking to flash.
but problem is that how can I do it. once I have tried but it open on fire fox but not on internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure IE isn't disabling PopUps

For AS3 use this code:

```
var path = "http://yourdomain.com/yourpage.html";    
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
    function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:openPopup('" + path + "');");
        navigateToURL(request, "_self");
    }
```

and in HTML page add follwoing javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
<!-- 
function openPopup(url)
{ 
    ww = 500;
    hh = 500;
    window.open(url,"","width="+ww+",height="+hh+",scrollbars=yes");    
} 
--> 
</script>
```

Comment: i have try ti . my IE enables popup

Comment: which version of flash you are using?